# send an email from a message string in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib, mime-message

this is probably a trivial question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I need to write a script that receives an entire MIME message in a string, as such:

```
From: Jerry Peek <jerry@ora.com>
To: mh-users@ics.uci.edu
Subject: New edition of "MH & xmh" covers MIME and MH-E
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----- =_aaaaaaaaaa0"
Content-ID: <1283.780402430.1@ora.com>

------- =_aaaaaaaaaa0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-ID: <1283.780402430.2@ora.com>
We've just released the new third edition of "MH & xmh: Email for
    Users & Programmers."  Changes include:
        - MIME (Multimedia) mail
        - The popular MH-E GNU Emacs front-end to MH
            ...omitted...

------- =_aaaaaaaaaa0--
```

and passes it on to an SMTP server.

I saw alot of examples that force me to parse the message and fetch the to, from and 
message data. is there a method that allows me to send the string as is?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might exists, but I do not think so. For the SMTP protocol ([RFC 2821 - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821)), you have 4 different elements : the SMTP server to which to connect, the MAIL-FROM enveloppe email address, the RCPT-TO destination address(es) and the DATA. All the headers are included in the DATA in SMTP sense.

So when using smtplib you have either to give a text message, a from address and one or more recipient addresses, or a parsed Message to allow smtplib to find from address and recipients in the headers. That's the reason why I think the short answer to you question is *no*.

Comment: thanks for the swift response, I'm off to write a wrapper function :)